# How to check if one function triggers another function with `Mocha`, `Chai`, `Sinon`

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai, sinon

How to create test with `Mocha`, `Chai`, `Sinon` to check if one function triggers another function.
I would like to check if `funcToTrigger` triggers `funcToSpy`

```
import { expect } from 'chai';
import sinon from 'sinon';

it('one function should trigger other function', () => {
  const funcToSpy = () => {
    console.log('I should be called');
  };

  const funcToTrigger = () => {
    funcToSpy();
  };

  const spyFunc = sinon.spy(funcToSpy);

  funcToTrigger();

  expect(spyFunc.called).to.be.true;
});
```

When I test only one function it works fine:

```
it('function should be called', () => {
  const funcToSpy = () => {
    console.log('I should be called');
  };

  const spyFunc = sinon.spy(funcToSpy);

  spyFunc();

  expect(spyFunc.called).to.be.true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [documentation](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/spies/#creating-spies-sinonspy-method-signatures):

> **var spy = sinon.spy(myFunc);**
>
> Wraps the function in a spy. You can pass this spy where the original
> function would otherwise be passed when you need to verify how the
> function is being used.

Usage examples:

```js
import { expect } from 'chai';
import sinon from 'sinon';

it('use Object', () => {
  const Test = {
    funcToSpy: () => {
      console.log('I should be called');
    },
  };

  const funcToTrigger = () => {
    Test.funcToSpy();
  };

  const spyFunc = sinon.spy(Test, 'funcToSpy');

  funcToTrigger();

  expect(spyFunc.called).to.be.true;
});

it('use Function', () => {
  const funcToSpy = () => {
    console.log('I should be called');
  };

  const spyFunc = sinon.spy(funcToSpy);

  const funcToTrigger = () => {
    spyFunc();
  };

  funcToTrigger();

  expect(spyFunc.called).to.be.true;
});

it('use Function Argument', () => {
  const funcToSpy = () => {
    console.log('I should be called');
  };

  const funcToTrigger = (funcToSpy) => {
    funcToSpy();
  };

  const spyFunc = sinon.spy(funcToSpy);

  funcToTrigger(spyFunc);

  expect(spyFunc.called).to.be.true;
});
```

Result:

```
$ npx mocha index.spec.js


I should be called
  ✓ use Object
I should be called
  ✓ use Function
I should be called
  ✓ use Function Argument

  3 passing (3ms)

$
```

Your test fail because: `funcToTrigger` has defined and always calls the original `funcToSpy`.

In the 'use Object' case, `funcToTrigger` calls method inside object `Test`, which has been replaced by spy, which is wrapping `funcToSpy`.

In the 'use Function' case, `funcToTrigger` calls spy directly, and the spy is wrapping `funcToSpy`.

In the 'use Function Argument' case, `funcToTrigger` calls first argument which is a spy, which is wrapping `funcToSpy`.